# AngularJS - Do I need $scope.$apply when using $http

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Do I need to call $scope.$apply when I make an ajax call using $http ?

Looks like it isn't needed because my code still works, and when I used JQuery ajax I needed to call apply or it didnt work.

So just to be completely sure, can I skip the apply calls now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AngularJS version 1.1.x you will need to add `Scope.$apply` if triggering `$http` calls outside of the AngularJS `$digest` cycle.

Detailed explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17271385/1418796

Comment: and what cases would trigger $http outside the normal angular cycle? only timeouts and ajax that is not triggered by $timeout or $http ?

Comment: @RogerAlsing yes those are the main times.  IF you're using timeouts consider using [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout)

Comment: @RogerAlsing also all the `$http` request triggered from regular DOM event handlers (usually in directives).